# Advice on how to avoid costly repaint in my carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm writing a carousel script that slides images using web-transitions.

Here's a really simplified fiddle into how it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/tUhZe/6/

I wanted to know if anyone can has any bright ideas into how I can reduce the costly repaints that occur at the beginning of each transition?

I tried adding 50 images to this carousel and it caused significant issues in performance.

```
    window.setInterval( function () {
        var element = $('#container'),
            active = $('.active'),
            next = active.next('.slide');
        if (!next.length) {
            next = element.find('.slide:eq(0)');
        }

        // Move next image into position, ready to slide
        next.addClass('next');

        // Slight delay for next image to move into position
        window.setTimeout( function () {
            // Start moving active image out
            active.addClass('prev');

            // Start moving next image in
            next.addClass('active')
                .removeClass('next')
                .bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function () {

                    next.unbind('webkitTransitionEnd');

                    // Move offscreen
                    active.removeClass('active prev next');

                    // Reassign active
                    active = next;
                });
        }, 100);

    }, 2000);
```

In a nutshell, this is how it script works:

1. The active image is in view (given class "active"). All other images (without class "active") are offscreen (top: 9999px).
2. The next image is moved beside the active image in preparation for the transition.
3. The active and next image classes are changed which triggers both to slide from left-to-right at the same time.
4. At the end of the transition, the active image is positioned offscreen.

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that a lot of browser/computer hardware combinations aren't quite ready for 50 fullscreen images to be loaded into the window at once.

However I recently built a similar carousel, and found that by the clever use of background images and simple logic you can avoid performance issues entirely.

The browser has problems when too many images are on the screen hidden or otherwise right? so therefore if we simply use spans with background images that are only loaded when the element containing the is either active or the preceding/following element.

i'm not great with words so let me show you;

http://jsfiddle.net/DUWMy/

```
<div class="slideshow">

    <span class="image-1 active"></span>
    <span class="image-2"></span>
    <span class="image-3 prev"></span> 

</div>



.slideshow .prev.image-1,
.slideshow .active.image-1{ background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-7.jpg'); }
.slideshow .prev.image-2,
.slideshow .active.image-2{ background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-400-300-5.jpg'); }
.slideshow .prev.image-3,
.slideshow .active.image-3{ background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-400-300-7.jpg'); }
```

In the above fiddle i've just thrown together a quick slideshow, the important thing to notice is that in the css the background images are not applied unless either a class of active or prev is present.

http://jsfiddle.net/DUWMy/1/

The above fiddle simply shows all elements on screen, you can see as soon as an element looses the class of prev and active it looses the background image. This means less images on the screen and hey presto you shouldn't experience all that extra lag.

You may have already found another solution, but this is a handy method to keep in mind. Also works well with responsive layouts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jai.
Yes I resorted to loading each image into the DOM as they were needed. So at most, there are two images in the DOM at once.
Changing the background image on an element is an interesting idea though. I did want there to be a transitional effect (slide/fade) when swapping between images, so this might be a bit limited with using backgrounds. Worth investigating though.